# How do I assert AJAX complete and redirect using Capybara 2.1?

Tags: javascript, selenium, capybara

I have a page with a form. When the form is submitted, an AJAX call is made to the server. If it succeeds, the page redirects to a new page using JavaScript as follows:

```
$('form').bind('ajax:success', function(){
   window.location = redirect_url;
});
```

How can I test this redirect using Capybara? I'm using the Selenium webdriver with Capybara. Filling out and submitting the form is easy, but I'm not sure how to test this AJAX + redirect combo.

It seems `wait_until` was also removed in Capybara 2 (http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara), so I'm really not sure how to assert this redirect.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution to wait for a redirect.

```
def wait_for_redirect(url)
  start = Time.now
  while true
    break if current_path == url
    if Time.now > start + 20.seconds
      fail "Redirect failed!"
    end
    sleep 0.5
  end
end
```

And now I can just call `wait_for_redirect "/some/url/here"`.